# Alternatives to root finding algorithms that limit accuracy by x (and not by f(x))

Tags: optimization, roots, numerical-optimization

I have a costly scalar black box function $f(x)$ and want to find the root $x_0$ with $f(x_0) = 0$ of that function.

Several root finding algorithms I have seen so far (e. g. *brent*, *ridder*, [toms748](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.toms748.html#scipy.optimize.toms748)) limit the accuracy of the solution by how much $x_{result}$ is away from $x_0$.

For me it is much more interesting to know how much $f(x_{result})$ differs from $0$. There are some algorithms that offer that (like: *broyden1* [scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.broyden1.html) / [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broyden%27s_method)), but it seems to me that the focus lies on setting the limits to $x_{result}$ and less to $f(x_{result})$.

My first question is whether there are variations of *brent* or *ridder* that allow to limit the optimization by $f(x_{result})$?

My second question is whether somebody has experiences or knows references where I can find the (dis)advantages of those algorithms that limit by $f(x_{result})$?

Comment: The main disadvantage of limiting by $f(x)$ rather than $x$ itself is usually it is the value of $x$ for which $f(x) = 0$ that people are trying to estimate. If $f$ is nearly level in some region around the root, and you stop when $f(x) < \epsilon$, $x$ may still be far away from the actual root. If all you need is some $x$ with low enough $f(x)$, this is okay. But if you need to approximate the root itself, it is not.

Comment: Also, it isn't hard to modify any of the methods to check the size of $f(x)$ instead of or along with the width of the interval. For example, in [this algorithm for Brent's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brent's_method#Algorithm), you can just change the "repeat until" instruction from "$f(b) = 0$ or $f(s) = 0$" to "$|f(b)| < \epsilon$ or $|f(s)| < \epsilon$".

Comment: Yes, thanks. Enhancing brent is presently exactly my approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest reason why terminating based on $\|f(x)\|$ is not so used is because you can easily scale your function with $\alpha f(x)$ for arbitrary $\alpha\ne0$, which will easily fool root-finders on when they should terminate. In most cases, this is simply an unreliable condition for termination.

Usually, this shouldn't matter anyways. For simple roots, you should find that $\|f(x)\|$ scales as fast as $\|x-x_\star\|$. For bracketing methods, a tolerance should usually be used to prevent $x$ from changing by less than a minimum amount. This way, you should not have one bound of the root converging rapidly and the other bound of the root stagnant, preventing $\|x_1-x_2\|<\epsilon$ from occurring.

If you do insist on using $\|f(x)\|<\epsilon$, then it usually suffices to redefine $f$ as follows:

$$\hat f(x)=\begin{cases}0,&\|f(x)\|<\epsilon\\f(x),&\text{else}\end{cases}$$

Most root-finders will terminate once they detect a root is found, so they can be fooled to terminate this way with any custom condition you desire.